# Prevent Bootstrap navbar from jumping down when resized to small window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here is a link to my markup, which is 100% relient on Bootstrap:

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify menu-icon"></span>             
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 6px;">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user user-icon"></span>
            <b class="caret"></b>              
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

On codepen: http://codepen.io/dsparry/pen/qEJen

You'll see when you make the window small, the right icon jumps down below the left icon and makes the navbar larger.

I want the navbar and icon position to stay the same when the window is resized. In other words, I don't want anything to change. I've tried to override Bootstrap with custom CSS but haven't been able to figure it out.

Any ideas? What CSS should I include to prevent the icon from jumping down when the window is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 ul

add classes to first ul : `col-xs-6`

add classes to second ul : `col-xs-6 text-right pull-right`

**edit**: that will break your layout.

You should have one UL with the intended right aligned li with pull-right at the first of the list like :

```
<ul class="navbar ...">
    <li class="pull-right ...">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

You can get help better if you do a jsfiddle